# How to put conditions on buttons in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to put conditions on buttons,
(browse button ) will browse image and (crop button) will crop that particular image..
Browsing is done good but I don't know how to pass same image file to crop button.
Would be grateful if any one will help me in this case

```py
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtWidgets,QtCore,uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow,QPushButton,QMessageBox,QStatusBar
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
    import sys
    import cv2
    fileName=0
    class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Window,self).__init__()
            uic.loadUi('Welcome1.ui',self)
            self.title="Gender_Identifier"

            self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("main-logo.png"))
            self.browse_button.clicked.connect(self.setimage)
            self.roi_button.clicked.connect(self.crop)

            button1=QPushButton("close",self)
            button1.clicked.connect(self.close)

            button2=QPushButton("file",self)
            button2.move(200,200)
            fileName=button2.clicked.connect(self.file)
            print(fileName)
            button3=QPushButton("set",self)
            button3.move(400,400)
            button3.clicked.connect(self.setimage)

            button4=QPushButton("set",self)
            button4.clicked.connect(self.crop)
            self.InitWindow()

            #IMAGE=self.set_image()
        def InitWindow(self):

            self.statusBar().showMessage("This is a simple status bar")
            self.setWindowTitle(self.title)

        def file(self):

            fileName ,_ =QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,"Select Image", "D:\python_data\interface","Image Files (*.png *.jpg)")
            return fileName
        def setimage(fileName):
           # fileName ,_ =QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,"Select Image", "D:\python_data\interface\images\preprocessed","Image Files (*.png *.jpg)")
            if fileName:
                #pixmap object
                pixmap=QtGui.QPixmap(fileName)
                #seting image inside that pixmap
                pixmap=pixmap.scaled(fileName.browse_label.width(),fileName.browse_label.height(),QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                fileName.browse_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
                fileName.browse_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                #return fileName

        def crop(fileName):
           # image=self.photo.getPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(self.browse_label))
            img=cv2.imread(fileName,0)
            height,width=img.shape[:2]
            start_row,strt_col=int(height*.40),int(width*.15)
            end_row,end_col=int(height*.60),int(width*.90)
            croped=img[start_row:end_row,strt_col:end_col]
            pixmap=QtGui.QPixmap(croped)
            #cv2.imshow("img",croped)
            pixmap=pixmap.scaled(croped.browse_label.width(),croped.browse_label.height(),QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            croped.browse_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
            croped.browse_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

            #cv2.waitKey(0)
            #cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    if __name__=='__main__':

        App=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window=Window()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

I would be very thankful for this.I searched as I could but didn't find satisfactory solution

Comment: You use the `self.selected_image` variable as a reference. That would be the easiest way.

Comment: would you elaborate a bit more ..would b thankful

Comment: please provide `Welcome1.ui`

Comment: @sabeenkanwal Ignore my initial message, I Was one the phone and didn't see the code below `self.browse_button.clicked.connect(self.setimage)`. I jus tthought you could save the selected image in a class variable, and access it from crop. Sort of like a temporary storage.

Comment: @ Torxed Sir you mean .. save the returned (fileName) parameter  in class variable ??

Comment: @sabeenkanwal Sort of. You should save the file name in an instance variable, not a class variable.

Comment: @ Heike check please I have edit  my question

Comment: @sabeenkanwal If you have another problem then create another question, those are the SO rules.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with your code. First off, since `setimage` and `crop` are instance methods, their first parameter should be the class instance itself, i.e. they should be defined as `def setimage(self, filename)` and `def crop(self, filename)`.

Secondly, the only parameter sent by the signal `QPushButton.clicked` is the attribute `QPushButton.checked`, so when you connect `self.setimage` to `self.browse_button`, `self.setimage` will actually be called as `self.setimage(self.browse_button.checked())` which is probably not what you. The way around this is instead of supplying `filename` as an argument to `self.setimage`, to save it as an instance variable, e.g.

```
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.fileName = ''
        ...
        self.self.browse_button.clicked.connect(self.setimage)

    def setimage(self):
         if self.fileName:
            #pixmap object
            pixmap=QtGui.QPixmap(self.fileName)
            #seting image inside that pixmap
            pixmap=pixmap.scaled(self.browse_label.width(), 
                                 self.browse_label.height(), 
                                 QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            self.browse_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.browse_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

To set the filename, `Window.file` would become something like

```
def file(self):
    fileName ,_ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,"Select Image", "D:\python_data\interface","Image Files (*.png *.jpg)")
    if fileName:
        self.fileName = fileName
```

`self.crop` would be similar to `self.setimage`, i.e. you would need to use `self.fileName` instead of supplying `fileName` as an input parameter. Also, `QPixmap` can't deal with numpy arrays directly AFAIK, so you would need to create a `QImage`first before creating a `QPixmap`, e.g.

```
def crop(self):
    if self.fileName:
        img = cv2.imread(self.fileName, 0)
        height, width = img.shape[:2]
        start_row, strt_col = int(height * .40), int(width * .15)
        end_row, end_col = int(height * .60), int(width * .90)
        croped = img[start_row:end_row, strt_col:end_col].copy()
        image = QtGui.QImage(croped, croped.shape[1], croped.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(image)
        pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.browse_label.width(), self.browse_label.height(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.browse_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.browse_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

Comment: The OP's `file` method returns a filename, so just put `filename = self.file()` at the beginning of both `setimage` and `crop`. Otherwise, the user will have to perform a separate step to choose the file. Also, the `crop` method needs an `if filename` guard to handle cancelled input.

Comment: @ekhumoro I agree with the `if filename` guard for `self.crop` and have edited my answer accordingly. In OPs original code, the filename is set only when the  `button2` is clicked (or that's how I interpreted OPs code at least) so I left it like that. I agree it's more user-friendly to not need two steps to choose a file and set the image but I leave that up to OP.

Comment: Thanku so much for guidence and correcting me..  (image = QtGui.QImage(croped, croped.shape[1], croped.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8)) in this line it is not just displaying messed up cropped image..where as in seperate code (crop) is working correctly

Comment: @Heike  how we know which type of format have to pass while converting (numpy image array) to Qpixmap ?? Because i pass(Format_Indexed8) but as a result it is returning messed up pixels..why is that so ?

Comment: @sabeenkanwal I'm not an expert on cv2 so I don't really know what kind of numpy array it produces. I needed `QImage.Format_Indexed8` to make it work with the image that I used as a test but maybe you will need a different format for your image. If you are only using cv2 to create a cropped image you could consider using `QPixmap.copy()` instead.